# Calling variadic Obj-C method multiple times causes invalid arguments to appear

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

I have a variadic method that I want to pass multiple enum values to:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Enum) {
    Enum0 = 0,
    Enum1 = 1,
    Enum2 = 2,
    Enum3 = 3,
    Enum4 = 4,
    Enum5 = 5,
    Enum6 = 6,
};

@interface Variadics : NSObject
- (void)test:(Enum)enm, ...;
@end
```

here's the implementation

```
@implementation Variadics
- (void)test:(Enum)enm, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, enm);
    for (; enm != 0; enm = va_arg(args, Enum))
    {
        NSAssert(enm <= Enum6, @"invalid enum");
    }
    va_end(args);
}
@end
```

And here is how I call it:

```
Variadics* var = [[Variadics alloc] init];
[var test:Enum1, Enum2, Enum3, Enum4, Enum5, Enum6, 0];
```

which works fine! But if I change it to this:

```
Variadics* var = [[Variadics alloc] init];
[var test:Enum1, Enum2, Enum3, Enum4, Enum5, Enum6, 0];
[var test:Enum1, Enum2, Enum3, Enum4, Enum5, Enum6, 0];
[var test:Enum1, Enum2, Enum3, Enum4, Enum5, Enum6, 0];
[var test:Enum1, Enum2, Enum3, Enum4, Enum5, Enum6, 0];
```

suddenly I hit that assertion and `enum == 4294967296`. Even weirder, I hit the assertion *on the first call*. The three later calls never even run.

What is going on?

Comment: Edit your question to include the declaration of type `LaunchTask`.

Comment: @robmayoff done

Comment: I have used variadic methods with multiple arguments and a variable number of enum values but my enum starts at 1. Is `completedError` declared in the header as `-(void)completedError:(BOOL)error orTasks:(NSNumber*)arg, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, even running many times. Have you tried moving this into a small test project to reproduce? Is everything being compiled at the same time, or are these in different modules? (This would be strange for `NSInteger`, but it can have different sizes, and that would cause your problem. I've had this kind of problem happen to me when someone redefined `BOOL`…) I would also make sure to dumb this down to just `NSLog` the values, and use a debugger to make sure you're passing what you think you're passing.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but you may also want to write your 0 as `(LaunchTask)0`. It shouldn't matter, but I'm just trying to eliminate any possible 32/64-bit issues around NSInteger.

Comment: The code you posted isn't causing the trouble. Something else is. Have you tried running under the address sanitizer?

Comment: @robmayoff I've boiled this down to a super minimal example and it's still happening. Check out my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your zero termination at the end of the argument list is being passed to your function as an `int` (32-bit) value, but your `va_arg` is pulling off an `NSInteger` (aka `long`) value from the stack. So you're suctioning in an additional 32 bits off of the stack and looking at all of it as one 64-bit value, half of which is the zero you intended and half of which is whatever happened to be adjacent to it in memory at that time.

You would have to do this to get the behavior that you want:

```
[var test:Enum1, Enum2, Enum3, Enum4, Enum5, Enum6, (NSInteger)0];
```

As Rob Mayoff clarifies in comments below, an uncast zero literal, being an integer value, is treated as an `int`. Normal C integer promotion rules apply*; in a varargs list, because the arguments have no declared type, smaller integer types are promoted to-- and passed as-- `int`s. Because the compiler has no visibility into the actual types you expect to see at runtime, that `int` will not be not promoted to `long` for you, thus winds up on the stack as an `int`.

Typically, varargs termination is either done implicitly (`printf` style foreknowledge of arg number and types) or with a constant like `nil` which will be the correct width, and those approaches avoid this issue. In the old 32-bit world where enum values were `int`s, *and* `NSInteger` was `int`, and the default integer promotion was *also* to `int`, these distinctions were hidden.

In practice, what this might mean for your code design is that you'd perhaps reserve a special sentinel enum value (not necessarily zero) to use as a list terminator to guarantee it was of the correct type. Or you'd perhaps modify to prepend the number of arguments to the function call.

*See C18 standard §6.3.1.1 ;-)

---

**Bonus Explainer: Why did you see the value `enum == 4294967296`?**

The decimal number 4294967296 is equal to `0x0000000100000000`. The second (lower) half of that was the 32-bit zero you put there. The upper half looks like it's just the number `1`. At first I assumed that this would be some other (valid) part of the current stack frame, but some investigation (on a 64-bit Mac using current llvm with Xcode, etc) shows that the compiler sets up the call to `-test:...` by pushing the enum args with `movq` (move quad =64bit) and the final zero arg with `movl` (move long =32bit). Because the stack is 64-bit aligned, a "hole" of 32-bits is left (ie, not overwritten) in the stack memory between the penultimate and terminal args. That's the spot that contained the `0x1`. So you're not reading an adjacent argument, or other value that's valid but used for something else. You're reading a ghost value from some earlier function call's workspace. In my debugging, it doesn't appear to be from the alloc/init of `Variable`-- it's something prior and unrelated to the test code at hand.

Comment: It's absolutely expected. An uncast literal `0` is an `int`, and in a variadic argument list, smaller integral types (like `char` and `short`) are promoted to `int` but `int` is not promoted to `long`.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for making that explicit. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched to passing `NSArray<NSNumber*>` instead. This variadic approach is too easy to get wrong since the compiler gives almost no help.

Comment: @Max Seems reasonable. Variadic functions feel to me like very ancient magic: you can still create them if you wish and they can be quite powerful but have sharp corners, and are perhaps not an ideal fit with the modern world.